# Problema ao adicionar foto ao banco de dados, oque fazer?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, imagem

Escolho uma foto por meio dessa parte do codigo em uma pagina php:

```
<label for="foto">Foto:</label>
<input type="file" name="foto"><br><br>
```

E depois preciso cadastrar ela em um campo blob no banco de dados, estou usando isso:

```
if($foto != NULL) { 
    $nomeFinal = time().'.jpg'; 
    if (move_uploaded_file($foto['tmp_name'], $nomeFinal)) {
        $tamanhoImg = filesize($nomeFinal);
        $mysqlImg = addslashes(fread(fopen($nomeFinal, "r"), $tamanhoImg));
        mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die("Impossível Conectar"); 
        @mysql_select_db($banco) or die("Impossível Conectar"); 

        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO jogador(nomej, foto, nometime)
        VALUES('$nomej', 'mysqlImg','$nometime')")
        or die("O sistema não foi capaz de executar a query");

        unlink($nomeFinal);
        header("location:addjogador.php");
    } 
} else { echo"Você não realizou o upload de forma satisfatória.";
```

o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Qual problema? não funciona? não grava? da erro?

Answer (score 1):

Perceba que na Query o **mysqlImg** esta como uma string, e não a variável em si. Creio que seja isso.

Answer (score 0):

Precisa adicionar enctype ao elemento FORM:
Por Exemplo:

```
    <form action="script.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
       Seu arquivo: 
       <label for="foto">Foto:</label>
       <input type="file" name="foto"><br><br>
    </form>
```